# is it possible to connect an AWS autoscaling group with an application load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working with AWS cloudformation I have an autoscaling group for a couple of machines running an API server, and I would like to set up an application load balancer as a single entry point, so that client application only sees one URL. I was able to create the load balancer and the autoscaling group but I don't know how to connect them.

```
Resources:
  NodeLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
      # IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
      ImageId: !Ref NodeImageId
      InstanceType: !Ref NodeInstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      # SecurityGroups is like this on purpuse, this work, IGNORE the error message if any
      SecurityGroups: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 200
            VolumeType: gp2
            DeleteOnTermination: true

  NodeGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    DependsOn: LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref NodeLaunchConfig
      DesiredCapacity: "1"
      MinSize: "0"
      MaxSize: "10"
      # TargetGroupARNs:
      #   - !Ref LoadBalancer
      TerminationPolicies:
        - NewestInstance
      # VPCZoneIdentifier is like this on purpuse, this work, IGNORE the error message if any
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-node
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Department
          Value: AI
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref Environment
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Job
          Value: KubernetesGroupNode
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MaxBatchSize: 1
        MinInstancesInService: 1
        PauseTime: PT5M

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: decrypt-loadbalancer
      # SecurityGroups is like this on purpuse, this work, IGNORE the error message if any
      SecurityGroups: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      # Subnets is like this on purpuse, this work, IGNORE the error message if any
      Subnets: !Ref Subnets
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-node
        - Key: Owner
          Value: !Ref Owner
        - Key: Department
          Value: AI
        - Key: Env
          Value: !Ref Environment
        - Key: Job
          Value: KubernetesGroupNode
      Type: application
```

Answer (score 5):

Your CloudFormation template currently has the following resources:

- A Launch Configuration
- An Auto Scaling Group
- A Load Balancer

Follow these steps in sequence to attach the auto scaling group to the load balancer:

1. Add a listener resource to your CloudFormation template, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener.html). Set its `LoadBalancerArn` property to the load balancer's ARN.
2. Add a target group resource to your CloudFormation template, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html).
3. Add a "listener rule" resource to your CloudFormation template, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html). Set its `ListenerArn` property to the listener's ARN. In its `Actions` property, add a `forward` action & provide the target group's ARN like this:

```
Actions:
- Type: forward
  TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
```

4. Add the target group's ARN to the `TargetGroupARNs` property of the auto scaling group, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns).

If you prefer to visualize a chain of CloudFormation resources linking the load balancer to the auto scaling group, it'll look like this:

[image]

Here's a complete example: [LB to ASG Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule--examples--HTTP_Header_Rule_Example--yaml).